# How can executing more instructions speed up exection

Tags: assembly, intel, timing

When I run the following function, I get somewhat unexpected results.

On my machine, the code below consistently takes about 6 seconds to run. However, if I uncomment the "`;dec [variable + 24]`" line, *therefore executing more code* it takes about 4.5 seconds to run. Why?

```
.DATA
variable dq 0 dup(4)
.CODE             

runAssemblyCode PROC
    mov rax, 2330 * 1000 * 1000
start:
    dec [variable]
    dec [variable + 8]
    dec [variable + 16]
    ;dec [variable + 24]
    dec rax
    jnz start
    ret 
runAssemblyCode ENDP 
END
```

I have noticed that there are similar questions already on Stack Overflow, but their code samples are not as simple as this and I couldn't find any succinct answers to this question.

I have tried padding the code with *nop* instructions to see if it is an alignment problem, and also set the affinity to a single processor. Neither made any difference.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you try padding before start with nops to adjust the cache line from that end?  You are probably just smoothing out the distribution of tasks across the decode and execute paths, may have found a sequence that aggravates them then provided a remedy with the extra instruction.

Comment: dumb question:  how do I assemble this, this is intel syntax yes?  can I use gcc/gas?

Comment: got it, are you trying to decrement bytes, words, dwords?

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is *because modern CPUs are extremely complex*. There is a lot going on under the hood that appears unpredictable or random to the observer.

Inserting that extra instruction might cause it to schedule instructions differently, which, in a tight loop like this, might make a difference.  But that's just a guess.

As far as I can see, it touches the same cache line as the previous instruction, so it doesn't seem to be a kind of prefetching. I can't really think of a logical explanation, but again, the CPU makes use of a lot of undocumented heuristics and guesses to execute code as fast as possible, and sometimes, that means weird corner cases where they fail, and the code becomes slower than you'd expect.

Have you tested this on different CPU models? Would be interesting to see if this is just on your specific CPU, or if other x86 CPUs exhibit the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

bob.s

```
.data
variable:
    .word 0,0,0,0
    .word 0,0,0,0
    .word 0,0,0,0
    .word 0,0,0,0
    .word 0,0,0,0
    .word 0,0,0,0

.text
.globl runAssemblyCode
runAssemblyCode:
  mov    $0xFFFFFFFF,%eax

start_loop:
  decl variable+0
  decl variable+8
  decl variable+16
  ;decl variable+24
  dec    %eax
  jne    start_loop
  retq
```

ted.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

void runAssemblyCode ( void );

int main ( void )
{
    volatile unsigned int ra,rb;

    ra=(unsigned int)time(NULL);
    runAssemblyCode();
    rb=(unsigned int)time(NULL);
    printf("%u\n",rb-ra);
    return(0);
}
```

gcc -O2 ted.c bob.s -o ted

this was with the extra instruction:

```
00000000004005d4 <runAssemblyCode>:
  4005d4:   b8 ff ff ff ff          mov    $0xffffffff,%eax

00000000004005d9 <start_loop>:
  4005d9:   ff 0c 25 28 10 60 00    decl   0x601028
  4005e0:   ff 0c 25 30 10 60 00    decl   0x601030
  4005e7:   ff 0c 25 38 10 60 00    decl   0x601038
  4005ee:   ff 0c 25 40 10 60 00    decl   0x601040 
  4005f5:   ff c8                   dec    %eax
  4005f7:   75 e0                   jne    4005d9 <start_loop>
  4005f9:   c3                      retq   
  4005fa:   90                      nop
```

I dont see a difference, maybe you can correct my code or others can try on their systems to see what they see...

that is an extremely painful instruction plus if you are doing something other than byte based memory decrements that is unaligned and going to be painful for the memory system. so this routine should be sensitive to cache lines as well as number of cores, etc.

it took about 13 seconds with or without the extra instruction.

amd phenom 9950 quad-core processor

on an

Intel(R) Core(TM)2 CPU          6300

took about 9-10 seconds with or without the extra instruction.

A two processor:
Intel(R) Xeon(TM) CPU

took about 13 seconds with or without the extra instruction.

On this:
Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     T7500

8 seconds with or without.

All are running Ubuntu 64 bit 10.04 or 10.10, might be an 11.04 in there.

Some more machines, 64 bit, ubuntu

Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5450 (8 core)

6 seconds with or without extra instruction.

Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5405 (8 core)

9 seconds with or without.

What is the speed of your DDR/DRAM in your system?  What kind of processor are you running (cat /proc/cpuinfo if on linux).

Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5440 (8 core)

6 seconds with or without

Ahh, found a single core, xeon though:
 Intel(R) Xeon(TM) CPU

15 seconds with or without the extra instruction

Comment: I think it should be `decq`, I don't know how much of difference it'll make though.

Comment: I tried decq on only one of the machines, no difference with or without that instruction.  I am not trying to disprove the original question in any way, hoping to find a way or place to repeat it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that bad. On average, the complete loop takes 2.6 ns to execute, while the other takes 1.9 ns. Assuming a 2GHz CPU, which has a period of 0.5 ns, the difference is about `(2.6 - 1.9) / 0.5 = 1 clock cycle` per loop, nothing surprising.
The time difference becomes so noticeable, though, due to the number of cycles you requested: `0.5 ns * 2330000000 = 1.2 seconds`, the difference you observed.

Comment: Nothing surprising? Why isn't it surprising that executing one more instruction shaves one cycle off the execution time of a loop iteration? The OP isn't asking how much of a difference it's going to make, but why the difference exists at all. What happens that makes the shorter version *slower*?

Comment: @jalf: oh wait, I misunderstood the question. I though the shorter version was the faster one ;)

Comment: Ah, your answer makes a lot more sense then. :)